# Ошибка Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Он говорит что тут ошибка я не могу понять почему сама ошибка находиться на строке где if.
Подключение правильное я проверял

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "first");
$name = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login` LIKE ".trim($data['login']));
if($name -> num_rows != 0) { 
        $error[] = "логин ".$data['login']." уже существует";
    }
```

Comment: никогда не пиши переменную прямо в запрос. у тебя **всегда** будут ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем запросе вы забыли поставить trim($data['login']) в кавычки. Следовательно, mysqli_query вернул false вместо объекта, а значит, получить свойство num_rows от булевого типа - невозможно.